# Sticky Caption on hover images in fluid grid layout

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I am new to Web Designing. I am doing designing using Dreamweaver CS6 Fluid Grid Layout having  17 column grid in full width PC.

i am not showing the full code. i am just showing the main Content where i got a problem. The problem comes is the caption are placed right downside the figure. it doesn't become invisible as i can say there is not effect of overflow:hidden; on it. It just stick downside the figure img. i want caption to become invisible and only shows when i hover over images...

**HTML5 index.html**

```
<div id="header">...</div>

<div id="wrapperContent">

<div id="div1">
<figure><img src="img/1.jpg"></figure>
<figcaption><a href="#">Manage Store Admin</a></figcaption>
</div>

<div id="div2">
<figure><img src="img/1.jpg"></figure>
<figcaption><a href="#">Manage Store Admin</a></figcaption>
</div>

<div id="div3">
<figure><img src="img/1.jpg"></figure>
<figcaption><a href="#">Manage Store Admin</a></figcaption>
</div>

<div id="div4">
<figure><img src="img/1.jpg"></figure>
<figcaption><a href="#">Manage Store Admin</a></figcaption>
</div>

</div>

<div id="footer">Copyright...</div>
```

**CSS File**

```
figure, figure img
{
width: 300px; height: 500px; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; overflow:hidden;
}

figcaption, figcaption a
{
font-family: Baskerville; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); font-size: 1.5em;
padding: 0.5rem; text-align: center; color:#fff; position: relative;
text-decoration: none; bottom: 0px; transition: 2s all;
}

figure:hover figcaption a
{
bottom: 10px;
}
```

**In Fluid Grid Layout layout.css**

```
#wrapperContent
{
clear:both; float:left; margin-left: 0px; width: 100%; display:block;
}

#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4
{
clear:none; float: left; margin-left: 1.3761%; width: 22.477%;
max-width: auto; display:block; height: 100%;
}
```

i have shown here all the code. please reply quickly so i can proceed on my project

Comment: Okay... What's the problem?

Comment: caption or we can say link which i have displayed under figcation is displayed under figure. i have also given overflow:hidden; then also it remains visible under image. also when i hover over images it is not coming up over the images. it just stick under figure img

Comment: @Paulie_D: There is no need of any javascript code or anything as i don't want any special effect. i just want to show caption on hover images. when i place it directly in <body> it works perfectly but, when i placed it under <div> in fluid grid layout it isn't working anymore...

Comment: It's not about JS....JSFiddle.net is a site that allows you to add HTMl/CSS in a live saveable way so you can demonstrated the issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Thanks i am looking forward to it

Comment: Also,your HTML is incorrect. `figcaption` should be a child (inside) the `figure`.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Thanks you for solving my silly doubt..now it is working perfectly...thank you very much